# DataTable continued columns?

Tags: datatables

I have a data table like this:
[image]

As you can see, there's a lot of unused vertical space.

Is it possible to have the values continue vertically once it reaches the end of the visible rows? Something like this:

[image]

Or should I just make 2 tables next to each other?